# Does json_encode add additional quotes?

Tags: php, json

http://codepad.org/zmsXbqhu

I have very simple code (viewable above):

```
<?php
$js = json_encode( "HO" );
var_dump( $js );
?>
```

It returns a string with extra quotes around it:

> string(4) ""HO""

Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are var_dump'ing. It wraps it in the quotes. If you don't var_dump and echo you will see the actual string.

Here, take a look at this:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/KB5Fkk

### Code

```
 <?php

$js = json_encode( '{ book : "how to use json", author: "some clever guy" }' );
var_dump( $js );

echo "<br /> The actual string:<br />";
echo $js;
?>
```

### Output:

```
string(61) ""{ book : \"how to use json\", author: \"some clever guy\" }"" 
The actual string:
"{ book : \"how to use json\", author: \"some clever guy\" }"
```

Comment: I know. lol. :) It's only because he used "extra quotes" in his question. Meaning that he acknowledges the existance of the "first" set of quotes.. at least that is what you can infer from that.

Answer (score 2):

In JSON...

> A *string* is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

[source](http://json.org/)

Comment: So how can I remove the additional quotes?

Comment: You *don't*. If you do, *it won't be JSON*.

Comment: Which quotes are you concerned with. Trying wrapping them with ** ** in your post so they are bolded. I'm confused now!

Comment: By _double quotes_ the documentation describes the following symbol: `"` (in the opposition to single quote: `'`), not two consecutive symbols like outputted by the `var_dump()` function. @Shamoon you really do not have any _additional_ quotes (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158930/does-json-encode-add-additional-quotes/6158998#6158998)).

Answer (score 2):

If you do it like that:

```
$json = json_encode("HO");
echo $json;
```

it will return the following:

```
"HO"
```

The reason your code returns something like that:

```
string(4) ""HO""
```

is that you used `var_dump()`, which can not be treaten as `echo`'s replacement (see [var_dump() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)).